# undefined method 'find_element' for Selenium::WebDriver:Module when using method from another module

Tags: ruby, variables, selenium, methods, scope

Hello I am new to programming working on Selenium using Ruby and I'm having some trouble. I am trying to call a method from a class in another module so I can create a sort of method library and every time I am returned the error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'find_element' for Selenium::WebDriver:Module` I have require_relative "LeadForm" to require the other module  and the code works properly when I put the method directly into the class I'm using it in but I would really like to just have it written once because this is something I will be using a lot.

The code is

> def self.progCNA
>
> Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(@driver.find_element(:name,
>   "area_of_study")).select_by(:text, "Health & Medical / Nursing")
>       Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(@driver.find_element(:name,
>   "concentration")).select_by(:text, "Nursing Assistant (CNA)")
>
> end

and when I call it in the the class that runs the test I put

> LeadForm.progCNA

and it appears to recognize and run the method but then the method errors out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this has been a source of a lot of frustration and I can't for the life of me find a solution online. I have looked up, down and sideways. If you require any more information from me please let me know and I will get it to you as soon as possible! Thank you very much.

I'm using
Windows 7 Pro sp1
JetBrains RubyMine 4.5.3
Ruby 1.9.3
selenium-webdriver 2.25.0

Comment: how are you instantiating @driver?

Comment: def setup  
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox  
    @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10  
    @verification_errors = []  
    end  

Putting that at the start of the main class I'm using. I also tried putting `@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox` in the other classes or methods but it didn't change anything except open another instance of WebDriver. @Allan Chow

Comment: Ah.  So you're instantiating a @driver class variable at uh "main.rb" and then expecting other classes to be able to get at the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the situation, I think you have a variable scope issue.

If you want to keep your class structure the way it is, I would update your method with...

> def self.progCNA(driver)
>
> Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(driver.find_element(:name,
>   "area_of_study")).select_by(:text, "Health & Medical / Nursing")
>       Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(driver.find_element(:name,
>   "concentration")).select_by(:text, "Nursing Assistant (CNA)")
>
> end

... and call it with

> LeadForm.progCNA(@driver)

You could... make a $driver global instead...

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! I knew there had to be a simple answer to this and I was bashing my head into it for so long that I finally gave up. Using $driver made it all run perfectly. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement element = driver.find_Element(:xpath=>regisCodePath)
String passcode=element.getAttribute('value');
```

Comment: Please elaborate. How does this answer the question?